# Node Postgres querying for json

Tags: json, node.js, postgresql

using node-pg I'm trying to lookup the existence of a string inside a  JSON object.

Example (part of) row:

```
{ viq_id: '801583',
    title: 'Blank, security key, lock system, and production method',
    applicants: [ [Object], [Object] ],
    cpc: [ [Object], [Object] ],
    abstract: { value: [Object], language: 'en' } }
```

abstract is of type JSONB.
When querying for this

```
 var query = 'SELECT viq_id, title, applicants, cpc, abstract ->> "value"' +
    ' FROM epo_patents' +
    ' WHERE title ILIKE $1';
```

or for this

```
var query = 'SELECT viq_id, title, applicants, cpc, abstract' +
        ' FROM epo_patents' +
        ' WHERE title ILIKE $1 OR abstract ->> "value" = $1';
```

or for this

```
var query = 'SELECT viq_id, title, applicants, cpc, abstract' +
        ' FROM epo_patents' +
        ' WHERE abstract.value = $1';
```

the answer is "errorMissingColumn", or in the latter case  errorMissingRTE

How do I properly query against JSON in node pg?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change `var query = 'SELECT viq_id, title, applicants, cpc, abstract ->> "value"'`  to `var query = "SELECT viq_id, title, applicants, cpc, abstract ->> 'value'"` , because double quotes used for db objects (table,column,etc) name...
look at [Postgres JSON syntax](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html)